# Stack Overflow Careers and Internships?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, students, internships

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

With the launch of this new career connection, I had a question concerning student signups. I know the primary goal is full time positions, but will internships be a part of this service? Is this not a good idea to mix with job postings? Maybe a future add on? Dedicated students are always looking for internship opportunities as they are great experience and a foot in the door in many cases.

Yes? No? maybe? 6-8 weeks?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In [candidate search](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products/candidate-search) employers can search specifically for interns.

If you're interested in being found for internships you can indicate that in the "search settings" section of your profile:

1. Click "employer view" then "edit search settings".
2. Tick the "Internship or Co-op" box.
3. Click the "save" button.

Then when employers search for interns (and you match their other criteria) you'll show up.

[image: Simple 3 Step Process]