# Does Stack Exchange offer internships?

Tags: discussion, jobs, stack-exchange-team, internships

As a high school student, a future college student, and someone who loves coding and answering questions on SO, I was wondering if there was a Stack Exchange internship, or perhaps something similar, for students to learn and develop their coding skills. If there were, that would be really awesome, and it would be a great experience. Is there a SE internship, and has anyone ever considered it?

Comment: Related: http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring - not sure if that's where they post internship positions.

Comment: Stack YTS! - where do I sign...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We don't currently offer any internships. If we ever do, they'll be posted on [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) and also listed here: [stackoverflow.com/company/work-here](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here).

Other companies do occasionally list internships on [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) - if you're interested in finding one, you might want to sign up and poke around a bit... See: [Stack Overflow Careers and Internships?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24960/stackoverflow-careers-and-internships)

Comment: Is [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24960/stackoverflow-careers-and-internships) still relevant these days?